# iOS > How to change text of remote notification received in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using [parse.com](https://parse.com/) to send push from user to user. 
My push notification looks like :

- *"+33654859636 sent you a message"*.

I would like to change this text if phone number is in my address book by

- "contactName sent you a message".

It's ok when the application is in foreground : in the function `"didReceiveRemoteNotification"`,

I have changed alert text before calling  `"[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];"`.
The method `"handlePush"` manage remote notification when the application is active.

- How does it work when the application is in background ?
- It seems to be a native behavior... Is there a way to change the text displayed at the top of the screen ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: yea there is a way to do this, I'm not familiar with parse so just tell you general idea. You need to switch to `silent push notifications` that comes directly to your app and then show `local notification` with any text you want, just goole a bit for highlighted words

Comment: ok @sage444, I will try your suggestion... Thanks for your help !

Comment: @sage444 your solution works well ! Thanks again :-)

Comment: glad to help, good luck with coding and using SO

Comment: @sage444 With this solution no notification is created when my app is not launched (neither active nor in background) :-( Do you know why and how can I fix it ?